# how to acces to svg elements from object jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I have multiple svg images contained by an object element everyone has its own id and all of them are different. All the svg are the same.

```
   <div class="body  ">
   <div class=" grid 18"><object data="diente.svg" type="image/svg+xml"id="diente18" ></object></div>   
        <div class="grid 17"><object data="diente.svg" type="image/svg+xml"id="diente17" ></object></div>
    </div>
```

What I want is modify the color of the polygons.

```
  $('.izq' ).on('click', function(){
        $(this).css('fill', 'blue')
  })
```

The svg code

```
        <path d="M0.5,39.5v-39h39v39H0.5z M1.85,38.5H37.4l-0.27-0.29h0.36l-4.96-4.99l-4.36-4.73h-0.34l-0.36-0.36l-15-0.04l-0.37,0.39
        h-0.24L1.85,38.5z M28.5,12.06v3.87l-0.15,11.65l3.08,2.98l7.07,7.66V19.91l0.22-17.25L38.5,2.87V2.23L28.5,12.06z M1.5,37.43
        l10-10V12.21l-10-10v0.61L1.19,2.53v34.54l0.31-0.31V37.43z M12.5,27.5h15v-15h-15V27.5z M12.96,12.16l15,0.04l9.51-10.02h-0.21
        l0.68-0.67H2.21l10,10h0.1L12.96,12.16z"/>
    <path class="figura" d="M1,1L1,1L1,1v0.66V1 M12,12v1v14v0.87l-0.05,0.05L11.88,28h-0.24l-0.29,0.29l-9,9L1,38.64V38v-0.04v0.68l1.71-1.71l9-9
        L12,27.64v-0.41V27V13v-0.59V12 M28,13l0,2.92l0,0.01v-2.71V13 M39,19.92v17.02V19.92L39,19.92 M28,27.94L28.07,28h-0.03L28,27.97
        V27.94 M31.06,30.9L31.06,30.9l1.84,2l0,0L31.06,30.9 M38.28,38.72L38.28,38.72L38.54,39H38H2H1h2.05h33.2h2.28L38.28,38.72 M40,0
        h-2H2H0v2v36v2h2h36h2v-2V2V0L40,0z M12.41,11l-9-9h33.31l-0.68,0.67l0.27,0l-8.56,9.03l-14.58-0.04L12.51,11H12.41L12.41,11z
         M2,3.98V3.41l9,9V13v14v0.23l-9,9v-0.68l-0.31,0.31V3.69L2,3.98L2,3.98z M38,36.94l-6.22-6.74l-2.93-2.83L29,15.93V13v-0.73
        l9-8.85v0.64l0.2-0.2L38,19.91V36.94L38,36.94z M13,27V13h13.82H27v0.22V27H13L13,27z M3.05,38l9-9h0.25l0.37-0.39l14.58,0.03
        L27.62,29h0.33l4.23,4.58l4.11,4.13l-0.3,0L36.25,38H3.05L3.05,38z"/>
</g>
    <g>
    <polygon class="izq" points="38,4.06 29.04,12.79 29,15.93 28.85,27.37 31.78,30.2 37.79,36.03 38,19.91 38.2,3.86         "/>
</g>
<g>
    <polygon class="derecha" points="10.74,12.23 2,3.98 1.69,3.69 1.69,35.86 2,35.54 10.74,26.81        "/>
</g>
<g>
    <polygon class="arriba" points="12.51,11 13.17,11.66 27.75,11.7 36.31,2.67 36.04,2.67 4.14,2.58         "/>
</g>
<g>
    <polygon class="abajo" points="32.17,33.58 27.62,29 27.26,28.64 12.68,28.61 12.31,29 4.12,37.64 35.99,37.71 36.29,37.71         "/>
</g>
<polygon class="centro" points="13,27 27,27 27,13.22 27,13 26.82,13 13,13   "/>
```

I read that it could by a html-svg problem but I don't know, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any `<object>` tags in your example. Also, are you duplicating any of your IDs?

Comment: no I didn't duplicate any, see again the post I edited it

Comment: There are several potential problems when manipulating `svg` inside `object`s. For instance, the `svg` DOM may not exist when you call your jQuery function. You may want to have a look at https://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/

Comment: thank you! I did it with ajax request but this solution is better, but there is a problem, I get this error  Uncaught TypeError: svgItem.setAttribute is not a function